# Back button inside of ActionBar how to finish current Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have 3 activities: activity A, activity B and activity C.
Users can go from activity A to activity C, also user can go from B to C.
when user go from A to C or from B to C I do not call finish() so C activity opens.
Inside of C activity I want to make back button (left top corner of the app) by clicking which current Activity closes.
If user came from A to C after closing C user will see again activity A
If user came from B to C after closing C user will see again activity B

How can I make back button like this? I suppose this such button have to finish current activity ant everything will be okay.
Usually programmers use
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
But in this case user go only to parrent activity A so this solution does not work for me

Comment: sorry, that happened by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

on your onCreate() Method. Then put this inside your activity class too:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case android.R.id.home:
          finish();
          return true;
     default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
}
```

The `finish()` function closes your current activity and navigates to the last visited activity in your application, in short words it goes back.